# When and when not to use role="button"

Tags: html, accessibility

In terms of accessibility, can someone describe to me the difference between a `<button>` and a `<a>` for screen reader and keyboard users? From what I can tell a keyboard user can use `ENTER` and `SPACE` to activate a button, whereas only `ENTER` for an anchor tag. In a Single Page Application I feel like the roles of these elements get somewhat confused and I'm not sure where the line draws between the two.

### Buttons that look like links

In my application I have a generic styling for a link, the class name for this is simply `.link`.

In the first example I have a button with an onclick handler that performs an action on the same page, therefore I've used a button element for it. However it stylistically looks like a link.

```html
<button class="link" onclick={(e) => console.log('Do the thing')}>This is a link</button>
```

If the roles are reversed and the link behaves like a traditional anchor where the route changes as a result of it being clicked, I'd do something like this:

```html
<a class="link" href="/route/change">This is a link</a>
```

Even though both of these *look* the same due to the applied class, should the anchor tag example have `role="button"` applied so it behaves like a button even though it's styled like a link? Is it better to maintain consistency between these styled elements for users with accessibility needs throughout the entire application, or is it better to interchange which gets the role applied to it based on the application of the element regardless of how it's styled.

### Two "buttons" next to each other

Following up on the first question. If the definition of an `<a>` tag is that it moves you to a different page/anchor point, should two side by side buttons which perform different tasks both be considered buttons.

Taking the following example, the confirm button performs an action on the same page, and the cancel button routes you back to the previous page.

[image: button example]

The code looks something like this:

```html
<button onclick={() => console.log('do a thing'}>Confirm</button>
<a href="/home">Cancel</a>
```

The definition of `role="button"` from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role) says the following:

> The button role should be used for clickable elements that trigger a
>   response when activated by the user. Adding role="button" will make an
>   element appear as a button control to a screen reader. This role can
>   be used in combination with the aria-pressed attribute to create
>   toggle buttons.

Should the cancel button have the button role applied even though it's technically not behaving in the way of the roles definition?

### Closing

Is there more concise guidelines on when these roles should and should not be used? Is there any harm in applying `role="button"` to any/all links that use the same styling if they are used interchangeably with the `<button>` element? Or should anchor tags and roles never mix, regardless if they stylistically look like another element type?

I appreciate you for reading. I'm attempting to take accessibility seriously but can't seem to find any clear and concise specifications surrounding use cases for this scenario.

Comment: A button is already has the button role, being a button. The idea is that you can (if really necessary) make other elements appear as buttons to those using AT. That's sort of implied in the MDN quote you posted. I'm not sure why you'd want to apply it to an anchor.

Comment: Right, but what about the other cases I discussed with links behaving as buttons and vice versa. Is there a clear definition as to when one should be used over an other or is it at your own discretion? You can't remove the role from a `<button>` element as it's already implied, but it looks like a link.

Comment: Why would you use an anchor if it's going to behave like a button? Use a button and style it accordingly. Bootstrap, for example, provides CSS for this exact case. Why would you want your user to think your anchor is a button when it behaves like an anchor? I don't understand that situation.

Comment: Should the style of the element dictate what role the element is? If I have something that looks like a button, but anchors you to another page, should it have `role="button"` even though it's not technically a button under the hood? Should a functional button that looks like a link have the same consistent role throughout the application, ie should all the same looking "links" have a button role if there's some button elements with the same styling. I'm not using Bootstrap, but the example you provided doesn't dictate how screen readers see the elements, or what the expected have is.

Comment: With what you're saying are you implying that an anchor should _never_ have the role of button?

Comment: I never say never, but I can't think of a good reason. Can you?

Comment: In the example I posted with two styled "buttons" next to each other

Comment: Styling is not a good excuse, in my opinion. I mentioned that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whenever i get this question of Buttons vs link I ask myself, is it scripted functionality or a is it Navigation(internal or external)?

- Buttons activate scripted functionality on a web page (dialogs, expand/collapse - regions).
- Links take you to another location, either to a different page or different location on the same page.

Coming to a11y

Role tells screen readers and other assitive technology the semantic category of an element, meaning the type of thing that it is. Every element already has a default role of some kind. The `<button>` element has an implied role="button", and the `<img>` element has an implied role="img" and so on.

role="button"

- if you use `<button>` don't add role (it's implicit)
- `<div role="button">` - (Adding roles do not cause browsers to provide keyboard behaviors or styling). Try to use real `<button>` If that’s problematic for styling purposes, you can use role="button". Be sure to add tabindex="0" to make it keyboard focusable, and ensure it works with both the Enter key and Spacebar, ensure it has proper disabled, hover, focus state, works in high contrast using media query.
- Don't use `<a role="button">` : it doesn't make sense in any way, it'll give you a block element just like `<div>` which you can style anyway, remember the question, it is a scripted functionality use
  `<button>` or `<div role="button">` , if it is a navigation use
  `<a>` without any role (style it the way you want)

Also, `<a>` cannot be disabled, `<buttons>` can be.

Screen readers have shortcuts to read out all the links eg NVDA user can press

- `K`    - jumps to Next link
- `INS + F7` it lists all links, headings
- `U`    Un visited Link Quick Key
- `V`    Visited Link Quick Key

I also think about do I want screen reader users to hear this link when they press `ins + f7` ?

EDIT: I missed to mentions assigning a role to an element overrides its native role. so `<a role="button"` is no more a `role="link"` and won't come up in `INS + f7` list and as it will be treated by the accessibility API as a button

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case I *would* recommend to use `role='button'` on the link since it's one of two choices the user has in this situation, and the two choices should appear in the same form (i.e. as two buttons), also for a user who hears it being read by a screenreader.

I just wonder why you use a link for the cancel option in the first place, and not a button right away...

Comment: Because the cancel button navigates you away from the page you're currently on. It still seems more semantically correct to not use the role of button here but I'm looking for documentation that proves one way or another.

Comment: You can add an `aria-label` attribute to that second button telling the user that this choice will bring him/her away from the current page.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easy : "**If it's not a link, it's a button**"

- A link should drive you somewhere else : another page, another anchor within the page.
- A link does not submit a form, does not perform any action.

In your example, "Confirm" and "Cancel" are actions : you're submitting your consent or explicitly indicating your desire to cancel your action. They should have the ARIA `button` role.

This is a different from "Continue" and "Back to the previous" page, which should have the `link` role.

Comment: I disagree that’s simple. Because the cancel button in my example drives you to another page and does not submit a form. What you’re saying isn’t entirely consistent with the example I provided. It performs an action, but that action is that of an anchor tag.

Comment: To follow up, is there any documentation or specification that supports this? I’ve heard very different opinions on this but nothing seems to be the “right” answer.

Comment: Your visitor doesn't and must not know or care what is the underlying technology (`button`, `form`, `a[href]`). What is important is to be predictable : I am in a `form`; I expect buttons to submit or cancel, not links.

Comment: But wouldn't that cause a problem with assistive devices where the user is given additional abilities due to it being an anchor tag vs a button? If it's incorrectly a button the user may not know that's going to take them away from the form?